# BroadCastReceiver in android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver

How to make activities that register BroadCastReceiver?

Because I need to close all the below activities if I click the close button from the last activity(Activity5.java)

(consider I have 5 activities namely,Activity1.java,Activity2.java,Activity3.java,Activity4.java,Activity5.java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How to make activities that register BroadCastReceiver?

if you need Broadcast in all activities then register via manifestXml and if for particular activity then

in onstart()

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"));
```

in onStop()

```
unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver);
```

Comment: Can you please send me some examples

Comment: via Manifest http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Comment: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/24/android-managing-multiple-broadcast-receivers

Comment: Not on onStop() - onPause()/onResume - onStop() my be never called